# Changing background color for Status Bar of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, statusbar

I'm using Excel 2016 (Office Theme:Colorful) and unfortunately when I write some code with a user defined text for displaying in status bar, the status bar changes its background color to dark green instead of remaining in vbButtonFace (&H8000000F). The result is an unreadable status bar text message, considered that the font color remains dark grey as expected.

I know it directly can't be done by VBA (please, don't suggest to me of changing Office theme... it's not an option!)

Googling around I found some code which uses API functions `SendMessage` and `GetSysColor` calls that I rearranged as follow:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const CCM_FIRST As Long = &H2000                    'Common Control Messages
Private Const CCM_SETBKCOLOR As Long = (CCM_FIRST + 1)
Private Const PBM_SETBKCOLOR As Long = CCM_SETBKCOLOR       'Progress Bar Messages

Private Const COLOR_BTNFACE = &H8000000F

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Sub SetStatusBackColour(hwndStatBar As LongPtr, ByVal clrref As Long)
        Call SendMessage(hwndStatBar, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0&, ByVal clrref)
    End Sub
#Else
    Public Sub SetStatusBackColour(hwndStatBar As Long, ByVal clrref As Long)
        Call SendMessage(hwndStatBar, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0&, ByVal clrref)
    End Sub
#End If

Public Function EvalCol(ByVal inCol As Long) As Long        ' Returns the RGB of a long colour value (System colour aware)
    If ((inCol And &HFFFFFF00) = &H80000000) Then EvalCol = GetSysColor(inCol And &HFF) Else EvalCol = inCol
End Function

Private Sub Test()
    Call SetStatusBackColour(StatusBar1.hwnd, EvalCol(vbButtonFace))
    'Call SetStatusBackColour(StatusBar1.hwnd, COLOR_BTNFACE)       'without GetSysColor API function call
End Sub
```

Now the problem is... How can I find the hwnd of the Excel Status Bar?

Obviously, if this approach doesn't apply anymore or a different approach can be used instead, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

You may work around this issue by updating screen before setting the value of status bar then turning it back to False.
For example:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = "Transferring Records: " & I & " of " & X & " completed..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```